# isinstance(object,type) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just going through some python help documents and came across the following piece of code :

```
isinstance(object, type)
```

Can anyone explain what does `type` mean in the above statement?

Thanks,
Vineel

Comment: Was it part of a concrete code sample, or more pseudocode-esque (e.g. a signature)? Or better, show the context. The snippet sadly makes sense for both.

Answer (score 14):

`type` must be an object denoting a type/class, such as `int` or `str`. E.g., `isinstance(1, int)` evaluates to `True`, while `isinstance(sys.stdin, str)` evaluates to `False`. If you've defined a `class Foo`, then `Foo` is also a type object.

**Edit**: as @delnan notes, `type` itself is also a type in Python, so `isinstance(str, type)` is true because `str` is a type, while `isinstance('foo', type)` is false. `object` is also a type in Python, and is the root of the type hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

`isinstance(object, classinfo)`
`object` - object to be checked
`classinfo` - class, type, or tuple of classes and types

The `isinstance()` returns:
`True` if the object is an instance or subclass of a class, or any element of the tuple
    `False` otherwise
    eg: `a = 1 + 2j`

```
print(isinstance(1+2j, complex))
output : True
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and make sure what in it is code and what is explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This statement checks if `object` has the type of `type`. The `type` variable should be a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
isinstance(object, classinfo)
```

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. Also return true if classinfo is a type object (new-style class) and object is an object of that type or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. If object is not a class instance or an object of the given type, the function always returns false. If classinfo is neither a class object nor a type object, it may be a tuple of class or type objects, or may recursively contain other such tuples (other sequence types are not accepted). If classinfo is not a class, type, or tuple of classes, types, and such tuples, a TypeError exception is raised.
>
> Changed in version 2.2: Support for a tuple of type information was
>   added.

Quoted from: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: where is a list of all the possible `classinfos`?